# jQuery Block UI - Updating "Please wait..." message with "Still working..." after X amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I cannot find in the documentation on how to update the Block UI text for long running processes. For example, saving changes to a form, depending on the options selected will trigger various processes some of which can take some time. I'd like for the initial block ui message to say "Processing..." and then say after 15 seconds, have it say, "Still working..." so the user doesn't think the page timedout. I've seen this done in gmail and would like to replicate that functionality. Any guidance available for this?

Comment: Have you tried [`$.blockUI({ message: "Still working..." })`](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#options)?

Comment: I have and that does work but I don't know how to determine how much time has passed. The insertion point I did it fires almost immediately. I recall back with prototype there was an ajax updater that would act like a "heartbeat" but I'm not aware of anything like that in jQuery or Javascript; perhaps I'm not using the right search terms though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that may help you is [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). It allows you to run some code after N milliseconds. There's a matching function, [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout), that will "remove" a `setTimeout` handler from the queue.

With these tools, you can structure your code similar to this:

```
var timeoutID;

function startBlocking() {
  // do your stuff...
  $.blockUI({ message: "Processing..." });
  timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: "Still working..." });
  }, 15000);
}

function stopBlocking() {
  // This is called whenever your processing is done
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

With this, the message will change after 15 seconds only if the process hasn't completed. When it completes, it effectively prevents `$.blockUI({ message: "Still working..." })` from running.

Comment: I did not realize I could utilize setTimeout like that.  Adding the logic now.

Comment: Would using setInterval() also be a possible solution?

Comment: @HPWD You could use `setInterval` but it's generally a better idea to use `setTimeout`, especially if you don't want it to repeat over and over again (but even then, using "nested" `setTimeout`s is a very good option).